# Rails not rolling back transaction after failed save()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, transactions

I have this domain model: A user has group of items, and the state of the items can fail a validation.

Validation works fine, and I even see exceptions get called when I use `save!`.

In my controller, I have this:

```
@user.items() << item

if @user.save
  render :json => {}, :status => :ok
else
  render :json => {:status => :error, :errors => item.errors}, :status => :bad_request
end
```

The first POST succeeds, and the second POST fails, but when I hit the index, I still see two objects, as if the second transaction never rolled back. What is going on?

My test is this:

```
  post :create
  post :create
  get :index
  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body).length.should == 1
```

Edit: Even when running a server, transactions are not being rolled back (sqlite3).

Comment: The item is associated with the user before save is called at all (assuming what you are counting is the items associated with that user)

Comment: item is not a saves object. @user fails validation when it contains duplicate items.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify which changes aren't being rolled back

Comment: The items are being persisted with the @user.save call, which lets the next call to get :index return those items via @user.items().

The nested association is sticking on the user object instead of rolling back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an item to the collection saves it immediately (unless the user is unsaved).
The call to save creates its own transaction and that is what is rolled back, not the transaction in which the item is saved

You could force everything into the same transaction by creating one explicitly.

```
begin
  User.transaction do
    @user.items << item
    @user.save!
    render :json => {}, :status => :ok
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  render :json => {:status => :error, :errors => item.errors}, :status => :bad_request
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're hitting a nested transaction problem in your tests.

I don't believe the Ruby driver for Postgres handles nested transactions, so you only get the scope of the outer transaction.  If you have transactional fixtures enabled, there's an outer transaction wrapping your test execution.  This means if your controller under test creates a second, inner transaction, and attempts to roll it back - you may not get the right behavior.

You can confirm the transaction interference by turning off the transactions in rspec:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

Comment: I set this to false, and I still see the failure.