# add to has_many association and use activerecord callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I have 2 models, Foo and Bar. Foo has_many bars. I'm trying to do something like the following in my Foo model

```
add_bar?(blah)
  bar = Bar.new
  bar.foo = self
  bars << bar
  save
end

before_save do
  #stuff involving bars that could potentially cause a rollback
end
```

That doesn't work because adding the bar to bars saves it, and I'd like the bar to only be created if the Foo is saved.

I saw [someone suggest using a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665269/rails-not-rolling-back-transaction-after-failed-save) and rescuing ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exceptions. However, save! throws other types of exceptions, and I don't think I want to catch every exception because that would mask problems that I do want to show.

I also tried saying in Bar's model

```
before_create { foo.save }
```

but that didn't work like I wanted. Even when save returned false, it added the object.And it seems like a weird way of doing it anyway.

What's the normal way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
foo.bars.build
```

To initialise a `bar` belonging to `foo`

Comment: so `bar = foo.bars.build` does the same as what i did above except it doesn't save it?

Comment: yes, is creates a bar belonging to foo, bar which is saved when saving foo.