# Rails validating with two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, bit confused on how to solve this issue.

I have one form and two models. Here is my form:

```
<% if @booking.errors.any? %>
  <% @booking.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p class="error"><%= msg %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @guest.errors.any? %>
  <% @guest.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p class="error"><%= msg %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for :booking, url: bookings_path do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag :email, "Guest's Email Address" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  <%= f.label :nights, "Nights" %>
  <%= f.text_field :nights %>
  <%= f.label :nights, "People" %>
  <%= f.text_field :people %>
  <%= f.label :nights, "Arrival Date" %>
  <%= f.text_field :arrival %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, the email field isn't part of the form builder. The email address will be used to create a  new Guest record if the email doesn't already exist. Once I have the ID of the guest then the booking record can be made also.

Here is the code for create action in my BookingController - where the form is submitted to...

```
...

def create
  accommodation = current_user.accommodation
  guest = Guest.find_or_create_by(:email => params[:email])
  @booking = accommodation.bookings.new(post_params.merge(:guest_id => guest.id))

  if @booking.save
    flash[:success] = 'The booking has been added successfully.'  
    redirect_to :controller => 'bookings', :action => 'index'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

...
```

I do realise this question isn't new but I can't find a good solution anywhere to my problem - I want to be able to set the form up properly (if necessary) and **validate** all fields using the two models. Then I need to display the error messages. At the moment, my email is ignored during validation and I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: In what sense is it being ignored? You are either selecting an existing guest or creating a new one if the email doesn't exist. Do you mean ignored when the form errors are shown?

Comment: Sorry yes - I don't know how to validate all the data as the validation rules are defined in two different models. So how can I validate email at the same time as the booking data?

Comment: Yeah, I remember your last question. Ever thought of using nested forms? http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: I have had a look at that vid actually. Is it really an issue to tackle with nested forms though? I guess I would have to change the form_for object to guest and then add fields_for for booking - even so - i haven't seen example of using validation rules from two models and displays the errors if there are any.

Comment: You could just leave the `form_for @booking` and then add the nested field for guest. Also, why are you using `form_for :booking` instead of `form_for @booking`?

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure of the difference. They both work but please explain if you have the time.

Comment: You should only use the symbol argument when your form is NOT associated with an ActiveRecord object. In your case, as in most cases, your form is connected to and AR object, so you should be using `form_for @booking`. One example of a form that is not associated with an AR object would be a contact form.

Comment: More info here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the easiest way to is to validate the email in the controller itself and add any validation error to the booking variable. Something like this:

```
def create
  accommodation = current_user.accommodation
  guest = Guest.find_or_create_by(:email => params[:email])
  @booking = accommodation.bookings.new(post_params.merge(:guest_id => guest.id))

  if @booking.save
    flash[:success] = 'The booking has been added successfully.'  
    redirect_to :controller => 'bookings', :action => 'index'
  else
    <% if params[:email].blank> %>
       @booking.errors.add(:email, "can't be blank.")
    <% end %>

    #You can do the same thing for whatever other validation errors you have

    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**Note:** I did not test the code

This is probably not the best way possible but it gets the job done and is easy. You could use accept_nested_attributes_for but it seems to me a little bit unnecessary considering that you are only validating an email. Nevertheless, if you want to do it the cleanest way, stick with accept_nested_attributes_for.

**EDIT**

Actually, your code is the right track. You just made a syntax error. The real reason your guests errors are not being shown is that you used a local variable instead of a instance variable. Try this:

```
@guest = Guest.find_or_create_by(:email => params[:email])
```

Your error messages should be displayed with the code you already have

```
<% if @guest.errors.any? %>
  <% @guest.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p class="error"><%= msg %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT 2**

In order to avoid a booking instance from beings saved in case the guest email is invalid you can do something like this:

```
if !@guest.errors.any? && @booking.save
    flash[:success] = 'The booking has been added successfully.'  
    redirect_to :controller => 'bookings', :action => 'index'
  else
```

Therefore, if the guest has any errors, the if statement will terminate before the @booking.save statement is executed.

Comment: yeah I thought about this but as I'm new to Rails I wasn't sure if it was a big "no no" to take care of validation in the Controller. I might well go down this route but I have been pointed in the direction of accept_nested_attributes_for before - could you possibly add to your answer for what would need to be done using nested_attributes? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I myself have never used accept_nested_attributes_for. But I think there is a cleaner way. I will update my answer.

Comment: got it going - was having a strange issue with the validation but reset my db data and all seems to be working on first check - will play around with it some more but that for the assistance

Comment: so looking at my Controller code is there a way to see if the @guest object is "valid" before I continue on with the rest of the create action - otherwise the booking record is getting created without the related guest record and this is causing errors!

Comment: I would say definitely a big "no no" to put validation in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a transaction. If one of them is invalid, rails will do a rollback and you can render the errors.

Follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665269/rails-not-rolling-back-transaction-after-failed-save) code, see if it helps.